# maven copy-dependencies vs defining dependency

Tags: java, maven

Maybe a simple question but I can't really figure it out why one would use maven-dependency-plugin instead of defining that particular dependency as standard maven dependency (i.e. using the `<dependency>` tag). What is the benefit of doing that? Is it supposed to be used if access to repository is restricted?

Thanks

Comment: Check out [the goals](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) of the `maven-dependency-plugin` to see what it does.

Comment: @Slaw I checked, I was investigating an issue I had and it led me to believe that this plugin was causing the error which feels stupid when I looked at it now, thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The goal `copy-dependencies` is not meant as replacement for a maven build, but either to download dependencies on the command line or to construct side artifacts that contain all dependencies.

Comment: that sums it up, I got confused because the mistake I made caused the plugin to fail to run and I couldn't see its result. Thanks